# How to store colors globally so that they are visible in js, css and html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I have a color theme for a website. So far I'm manually putting the color for each element each time it's used.

It'd be easier to have a set of global variables with the colors, such that if I decide to change one, I don't have to go through each file to manually change each instance to the new color.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

You can define a variable like so in your CSS:

```
body {
  --my-color: #000;
}
```

And use it anywhere later in your CSS or HTML like so:

```
p {
  color: var(--my-color);
}
```

or

```
<p style="color: var(--my-color)"></p>
```

And you can retrieve the variable value from JS by doing:

```
getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--my-color');
```

Now your variable is available from CSS, HTML, and JS.